# Trouble using the new operator please

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking at error:

```
C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

and saw that the new operator was needed so that I can create a dynamic array in MSVB. My code worked fine in Dev-C++, but I want it to work in MSVB.

```
int lines_in_file()
{
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;

    std::ifstream menu_file;
    menu_file.open("menu.dat");

    while (getline(menu_file, line))
        ++number_of_lines;

    menu_file.close();

    return number_of_lines;
}

void employee_menu()
{
    int lines = lines_in_file();
    int choice;
    std::string names[lines];

    std::ifstream menu_file;
    menu_file.open("menu.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines - 1; i++)
    {
        getline(menu_file, names[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines - 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Name " << i + 1 << ": " << names[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

I have searched on how to use the new operator, but I am not sure why the examples keep using `*` or `**`.

As you may be able to see, I am trying to get a menu to show a list of employees in a file. I will then use that menu to choose an employee and do further tasks.

Comment: making C++ code work on Visual Basic will be very tough task.

Comment: variable-length array is not portable c++ code.

Comment: Do you mind using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> std::string names[lines];
> ```

C++ (and even C in VS) doesn't support this.

You can use

```
std::vector<std::string> names(lines);
```

or

```
std::string *names = new std::string [lines];
...
delete [] names;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a vector there. Arrays in C and C++ are kind of weird. Only in C99 (and not C++) support for *automatic* storage arrays of dynamic length has been introduced. Note the *automatic* (which on most systems resolved to "stack"), so this puts a pretty strong constraint and many caveats on it. When using C++ you should avoid arrays where possible. Use a `std::vector` instead. Much nicer to use, gives you behind-the-scenes memory management that "just works" (unless you allocate a `std::vector` with `new` which, in my opinion, is just perverse) and modern implementations of `std::vector` do automatic reference counting so that if you copy vectors around the actual elements are only copied around when modified (CoW); that is much nicer than what a plain array gives you. So here it goes.

Replace this

```
std::string names[lines];
```

with this

```
std::vector<std::string> names(lines);
```

---

> I searched on how to use the new operator, but I'm not sure why the examples keep using * or **.

Because when dealing with `new` you're dealing with *pointers*. If you don't know how to work with pointers (yet), then you absolutely must learn how to use them first.

Comment: Alright. I was hoping I could use this area for an array. My C++ group assignment calls for us to use an array somewhere in the program. Our program is a payroll processing program and for the life of me, I have no idea where an array would be useful. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @SeanOoley: Ah, it's homework. Well in that case the whole point of the assignment is, that you learn how to use pointers and dynamic memory allocation (i.e. `new` and `delete`).